How to make a drawer item navigate to a stack navigator screen?
Is there a way to navigate to a stack navigator screen from the drawer navigator by clicking it? I mean:
<Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />

Here, I don't want the ProfileScreen to be a different screen, when I press to the item, I want to navigate to the ProfileScreen of StackNavigator. When I set the component value to null, or not use a component, errors come.
My stack is Drawer>Tab>Stack navigators. The skeleton is done using docs and also this page.
How can I achieve this?

Please provide more code of your app. Is the StackNavigator nested in the Drawer ? Or the opposite ?

@J.dev It is a general question I think. My stack is Drawer>Tab>Stack navigators. The skeleton is done using docs and also this link: https://dev.to/deversity/combining-drawer-tab-and-stack-navigators-in-react-navigation-6-l4m

Please provide how are you nesting the tab and the stack navigators in the drawer navigator. From the code you posted it is no clear what is ProfileScreen. If it is a stack navigation then it should open your first Stack.Screen from the stack (unless you have specified another screen to be your initial screen for that stack).

@Ale I am asking, isn't it possible to have an empty row (without a screen inside it, just text) inside Drawer Navigator, where if I press it navigates to ProfileScreen of Stack Navigator?

I think you can do so. If you have a Drawer.Screen like this <Drawer.Screen name='WebPage' component={ProfileStack} /> and your profile stack component is : <Stack.Navigator> <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen}  /> </Stack.Navigator>

Also note that the component property form Drawer.Screen is always required as it needs to render something, so not passing a component or just null will always trigger error.
